# Роутинг для постраничной навигации в Ruby on Rails приложении

Tags: ruby-on-rails, маршрутизация

В роутах Ruby on Rails приложения часто встречаются повторяющиеся участки, например, многие разделы имеют постраничную навигацию на индексных страницах, которую бы хотелось задавать не GET-параметром, а более красиво, например, так

```
/catalogs или /catalogs/page/1 - первая страница со списком каталогов
/catalogs/page/2 - вторая страница со списком каталогов

/pages или /pages/page/1 - первая страница со списком страниц
/pages/page/2 - вторая страница со списком страниц
```

В результате в `config/routes.rb` в дополнение к `resource`-определению роутов, появляются дополнительные `get`-роуты, задающие формат индексной страницы и необязательный параметр `:page`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  get 'catalogs(/page/:page)', to: 'catalogs#index', page: /\d+/
  resources :catalogs, except: :index

  get 'pages(/page/:page)', to: 'page#index', page: /\d+/
  resources :pages, except: :index
  ...
end
```

Команда `rake routes` приводит к следующему выводу

```
              GET    /catalogs(/page/:page)(.:format)  catalogs#index {:page=>/\d+/}
     catalogs POST   /catalogs(.:format)               catalogs#create
  new_catalog GET    /catalogs/new(.:format)           catalogs#new
 edit_catalog GET    /catalogs/:id/edit(.:format)      catalogs#edit
      catalog GET    /catalogs/:id(.:format)           catalogs#show
              PATCH  /catalogs/:id(.:format)           catalogs#update
              PUT    /catalogs/:id(.:format)           catalogs#update
              DELETE /catalogs/:id(.:format)           catalogs#destroy
              GET    /pages(/page/:page)(.:format)     page#index {:page=>/\d+/}
        pages POST   /pages(.:format)                  pages#create
     new_page GET    /pages/new(.:format)              pages#new
    edit_page GET    /pages/:id/edit(.:format)         pages#edit
         page GET    /pages/:id(.:format)              pages#show
              PATCH  /pages/:id(.:format)              pages#update
              PUT    /pages/:id(.:format)              pages#update
              DELETE /pages/:id(.:format)              pages#destroy
```

Есть ли способ получить точно такие же роуты, не определяя отдельный `get`-роут для индексной страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения задачи можно использовать роут-консерны

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  concern :pageable do
    collection { get 'page/:page', action: :index, page: /\d+/ }
  end

  resources :catalogs, concerns: :pageable
  resources :pages, concerns: :pageable
  ...
end
```

В этом случае команда `rake routes` будет содержать роуты, дающие тот же результат

```
              GET    /catalogs/page/:page(.:format)  catalogs#index {:page=>/\d+/}
     catalogs GET    /catalogs(.:format)             catalogs#index
              POST   /catalogs(.:format)             catalogs#create
  new_catalog GET    /catalogs/new(.:format)         catalogs#new
 edit_catalog GET    /catalogs/:id/edit(.:format)    catalogs#edit
      catalog GET    /catalogs/:id(.:format)         catalogs#show
              PATCH  /catalogs/:id(.:format)         catalogs#update
              PUT    /catalogs/:id(.:format)         catalogs#update
              DELETE /catalogs/:id(.:format)         catalogs#destroy
              GET    /pages/page/:page(.:format)     pages#index {:page=>/\d+/}
        pages GET    /pages(.:format)                pages#index
              POST   /pages(.:format)                pages#create
     new_page GET    /pages/new(.:format)            pages#new
    edit_page GET    /pages/:id/edit(.:format)       pages#edit
         page GET    /pages/:id(.:format)            pages#show
              PATCH  /pages/:id(.:format)            pages#update
              PUT    /pages/:id(.:format)            pages#update
              DELETE /pages/:id(.:format)            pages#destroy
```

Comment: Ничо так. Возможно, стоит ещё прикрутить для `:page` значение `1` по умолчанию. Хотя библиотеки разбиения, которыми я пользовался, успешно понимали `nil` как 1, это может стать неплохим примером.